# How to get action id to delete previously posted action on timeline

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using following code to post actions on timeline

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function read()
{
FB.api('/me/app_namespace:read' + 
'?article=http://example.com/test.php&access_token=','post',
function(response) {
var msg = 'Error occured';
if (!response || response.error) {
if (response.error) {
msg += "\n\nType: "+response.error.type+"\n\nMessage: "+response.error.message;
}
alert(msg);
} 
else {

alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
}
});
}
</script>
```

Now i want to use the following code to delete action but the problem is dont know how to save the "action id" from above code so that it can be used in following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function deleteAction()
{
  FB.api(
    '/actionid',
    'delete',
    function(response) {
       alert('action deleted')
    });
}
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends, are you looking to delete the action in a later session or current? In the current session itself, you can probably simply store it in a variable. For eg:

```
function read() 
{
    FB.api('/me/app_namespace:read' + 
    '?article=http://example.com/test.php&access_token=','post',
    function(response) {
    var msg = 'Error occured';
    if (!response || response.error) {
    if (response.error) {
    msg += "\n\nType: "+response.error.type+"\n\nMessage: "+response.error.message;
    }
    alert(msg);
    } 
   else {

   alert('Post was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
    var idToDeleteLater = response.id;
}
});
}



 function deleteAction()
{
  FB.api(
    '/'+idToDeleteLater,
    'delete',
    function(response) {
       alert('action deleted')
    });
}
```

As you can see, that's pretty straightforward, all you've done is stored the actionID in a variable. You can potentially store multiple IDs in an array or something.

On the other hand, if you want to delete the actions in a later session (unlikely for a "read" action), then you need to store these action IDs in a database or something, and pull the action from there prior to deleting.